# Abolute-positioned element within a relative one causing overflow in Chrome/Safari

Tags: css, css-position

The problem we're trying to solve is that text is overflowing past the end of a `<p>`. It seems to be the result of its contents, which include a relatively-positions `<a>` element, with an absolute-positioned `<span>` element within it, which has padding. Firefox wraps the text as I would normally expect.

Here's an abstraction of my HTML:

```
<p>
    In this second example, 
    <a href="#">
        <span class="icon"><img src="play.gif"></span>
        mo
    </a> 
    muh...
</p>
```

And an abstraction of the CSS, as simplified as I think still makes sense:

```
a {
    padding: 5px;
}
a span.icon {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the problem (the highlighting is Chrome's element inspector with the `<p>` element highlighted). You can see the word `immediately` overflowing at the end of the `<p>`:

[image]

Any pointers in the right direction appreciated.

Comment: Why use absolute positioning?  You should be able to do this just fine using `display:inline` or setting the `background-image` of the link and some padding.

Comment: Yup, using `display:inline` (actually, `display:inline-block` to be able to set the width) this worked out. By removing the `display:block`, Chrome is correctly wrapping. Care to add as a question, if you want me to accept as the answer?

Comment: Sure.  It would be good to help others with a similar problem.  I'll draft up an answer for you shortly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using absolute positioning, try using `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` (if you need to set height/width - Note: not supported in IE 7 and lower).

You could drop the `display` all together, because images and spans are inline to start with.  I have an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/JxqMp/2/) here removing the span and just styling the image and surrounding link.

You could also use the image as a background for the button, and set the padding to account for the space.  Example:

```
.button{
  background: url(img/buttonIcon.png) no-repeat; /* 15x15 icon */
  padding: 0 0 0 15px;
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/gXhMN/1/)